# When to use "una" and when to omit it

Tags: traducción, gramática

I recently came across this sentence:

> No tenemos fecha.

which means "We do not have a date." The context of this may be when making an appointment with the dentist and you are saying you do not have an appointment.

But why is "una" avoided, as doesn't one say

> No tenemos *una* fecha

Answer (score 3):

The difference is about generic specification. When you say **"No tenemos fecha"** fecha is undefined; there are many dates available. But, saying **"No tenemos *una* fecha**, the date is no longer generic and is countable. The real intention is to emphasize the fact that there is no date available (of course,  we are not really talking about a specific date.) Is the same as saying **We don't have **even a single date** available**.

Here are several ways you can emphasize:

> No tenemos fecha (no emphasis)
>   No tenemos **una** fecha (strong emphasis)

Also remember that in Spanish double negation is still a negation.

> No tenemos **ni una** fecha (strong emphasis)
>   No tenemos **ninguna** fecha (mild emphasis)

Other examples are

> No tenemos naranjas (We are talking about **naranjas** in a generic sense)
>   No tenemos **una** naranja (Although not a specific orange we are emphasizing  strongly that we don't even have one)
>   No tenemos *ni* **una** naranja (We are also emphasizing that we don't even have one orange.)
>   No tenemos **ninguna** naranja (The most natural way to say it in Spanish; with a mild emphasis.)

Answer (score 2):

In Spanish, the word "un/una" are not usually used to say "we don't have any ...". Actually if you add the "un/una" to the sentence, you should end the sentence with an adjective, for example:

> "No tenemos una fecha disponible."

which means "We don't have any available date."

Hope it helps.

Comment: The adjective at the end could be omitted based on the context though. To me, sounds the same. The explanation of "fecha is undefined" and "una fecha" is no longer generic are wrong as "una" is an "artículo indeterminado" that doesn't express a quantity you can count.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is one of these things where there is no grammatical rule. In this particular case, I understand that `fecha` is something generic, so it would be like saying `We don't have (any) dates`. So you don't need to add `una`, actually it sounds weird if you put it there. A different example could be: `No nos queda leche`, which means `We are out of milk` or `We don't have (any) milk`

A similar case (but slightly different), would be: `¡Ya tenemos casa!`, which means `We have a flat now!`. You don't have to add `una`or `la`. You are referring to "your flat", "the flat", the one that you wanted or needed.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In English, we tend to use the word "a" as an article a lot, just like Spanish uses "the" in the EL o LA forms. If this were to be written with Una, it wouldn't be completely wrong, rather just awkward since it's not as direct as possible. You really only need to use UN o UNA when referring to a quantity. In this case, the message was simple referring to one single thing, making it with out the Una quicker, more to the point and 'better' in terms of using it as a phrase.